# jQ Grid Unable to get property 'integer' of undefined or null reference error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid 4.5.4. I'm having a jqGrid javascript error in my ASP.NET MVC view. Visual Studio captures error of:

> Unable to get property 'integer' of undefined or null reference error

If I Break in the Javascript debugger and look at the View, the data loads, but with a box saying undefined.

I have followed the documentation and assured that the scripts are loaded in the view/layout output.

My View:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Admin.cshtml";
}

<h2>Manage Posts, Categories and Tags</h2>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab-posts">Posts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-cats">Categories</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-tags">Tags</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-comments">Comments</a></li>

    </ul>

    <div id="tab-posts" class="tab">
        <table id="tablePosts" class="grid">
        </table>
        <div id="pagerPosts" class="pager">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-cats" class="tab">
        <table id="tableCats" class="grid">
        </table>
        <div id="pagerCats" class="pager">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-tags" class="tab">
        <table id="tableTags" class="grid">
        </table>
        <div id="pagerTags" class="pager">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-comments" class="tab">
        <table id="tableComments" class="grid">
        </table>
        <div id="pagerComments" class="pager">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Head section of my layout file (_Admin.cshtml)

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Manage Posts, Categories and Tags</title>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
<link href="../../Content/themes/simple/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />
<link href="../../Scripts/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Scripts/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.src.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../../Content/themes/simple/simple.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/admin.js"></script>
</head>
```

My controller methods:

```
  [Authorize]
    public ContentResult Posts(JQGridViewModel gridparams)
    {
        var posts = _postRepository.AdminPosts(gridparams.page - 1, gridparams.rows, gridparams.sidx, gridparams.sord == "asc");
        var totalPosts = _postRepository.TotalPosts;

        return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {
            page = gridparams.page,
            records = totalPosts,
            rows = posts,
            total = Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDouble(totalPosts) / gridparams.rows)
        }, new CustomDateTimeConverter()), "application/json");
    }

    public class CustomDateTimeConverter:Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.DateTimeConverterBase
    {
        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType,
            object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value,
            JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            writer.WriteValue(value.ToString());
        }
    }
```

The initializing script in admin.js

```
$(function () {
      $(gridName).jqGrid({
        // server url and other ajax stuff 
        url: '/Admin/Posts',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',

        height: 'auto',

        // columns
        colNames: colNames,
        colModel: columns,

        // pagination options
        toppager: true,
        pager: pagerName,
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],

        // row number column
        rownumbers: true,
        rownumWidth: 40,

        // default sorting
        sortname: 'PostedOn',
        sortorder: 'desc',

        // display the no. of records message
        viewrecords: true,

        jsonReader: { repeatitems: false }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should verify that `grid.locale-en.js` exist really in the same directory as `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`. Typically all language files are in the subdirectory `i18n`.

In any way the error message

> Unable to get property 'integer' of undefined or null reference error

exist typically if you load `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` (or `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`) **without** loading of language specific file like `grid.locale-en.js`.

Comment: Yes, the scripts are in the same directory.

Comment: @arod: You use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`. So you should post the line number where the error take place. If `grid.locale-en.js` will not loaded (wrong path or no permission and so on) the you will have error in [the line number 1801](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.4/js/grid.base.js#L1801) because `$.jgrid.formatter` are defined in `grid.locale-en.js`. If you would comment (temporary remove) `toppager: true` and `pager: pagerName` the grid will not have any pager and you should don't see the error.

Comment: Oleg, it seems when Visual Studio when is debugging my Javascript it dynamically minifies so the text is very cryptic..so I can't provide a meaningful line number where it's breaking. Is there some way around this?

Commenting out the two lines of code does to remove the paging element does get rid of the problem. 

The localization file is definitely loading in my webpage. I downloaded it here: http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6  

Thanks

Comment: Also, the line of source code you indicated on line 1801 and the line of minified code are compatible.

    fmt = $.jgrid.formatter.integer || {};  //source code
    k=b.jgrid.formatter.integer||{}; //minified code

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue. The JQueryUI tabs containing the grids were not working correctly and not hiding the other divs in the tab set. Once I got the tabs working correctly the jqGrid rendered perfectly